# Create ASP.NET Core Web API backend container including restored database for frontend

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, containers

I need to create an API Docker container with a SQL Server 2017 database. That part isn't any problem. My problem is that I would like to restore a `.bak` file inside the docker container so that the frontend developer only needs to do a docker-compose up to get the whole backend running including the database with test data.

Any help would be appreciated ;)

My Docker-Compse file

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Api/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
            - db
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest"
    ports:
        - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
        - "sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql"
    restart: always
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "<password>"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

And my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Api/Api.csproj", "Api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Api/Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Api"
RUN dotnet build "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/tutorial-restore-backup-in-sql-server-container?view=sql-server-ver15#copy-a-backup-file-into-the-container) to restore a database in the container, you have to create a backup directory and copy your backup file into it. From there you can run the restore command.

You can do this steps also in your Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

RUN mkdir /var/opt/mssql/backup
COPY yourbackup.bak /var/opt/mssql/backup/.
COPY entrypoint.sh .
COPY run-initialization.sh .

ENV SA_PASSWORD yourpassword
ENV ACCEPT_EULA Y

CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

The `entrypoint.sh` could look like this:

```
/usr/src/app/run-initialization.sh & /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

The initialization script runs in the background and in the same time sql server starts.

The `run-initialization.sh` could look like this:

```
# Wait to be sure that SQL Server came up
sleep 90s

# Run the restore script to create the DB with schema & data
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'yoursapassword' -Q 'RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = "/var/opt/mssql/backup/yourbackup.bak"'
```